# Why am I suddenly getting bad audio quality when using TeamViewer?

Tags: audio, remote-access, teamviewer

I have been using TeamViewer a lot and everything worked fine but for the last few weeks, the audio quality got very bad.

Before that, after connecting, the audio quality was bad and after 10/20 seconds the audio cuts of for a second and after that the quality was perfect, like I would directly connect my headset to the client system.

But now the audio quality stays bad. I already set tv to "best quality" with no success.

It can't be the connection because the connection is local via IP address.

Is there anything that I can change to get the audio quality back up?

More information on the setup:

Remote system setup:

- **OS**: Windows 10 21H1 Build 19043.1466
- **TeamViewer**: 15.26.4 64Bit
- **Audio Driver**: Latest Nvidia High Definition Audio Driver

My client setup:

- **OS**: Windows 10 20H2 Build 19042.1466
- **TeamViewer**: 15.2.2756

---

Edit:
The sound via remote desktop connection is still very good, so only when using TeamViewer the sound will get bad.

Comment: https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/101254/teamviewer-sound-issues-used-to-work-fine-now-horrendously-muffled-very-low-quality

Comment: I tryed that and other qualitys but the audio was still bad, even after a reconnect

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a somewhat broad assumption that you are using a sony bluetooth headset or other headset that include hands-free calling as well as standard bluetooth audio.

when teamviewer tries to use your bluetooth device it is changing which audio driver is being used from your high quality standard BT audio driver to your hand-free calling audio driver. the only way i've found to fix this is to set teamviewer to use any random audio device that is NOT your bluetooth device (in my case I set it to use my TV). very inconvenient yes, but at least with this fix teamviewer doesn't ruin your audio experience for every piece of software on your computer.

hopefully teamviewer will fix this but I have a hunch they wont. other softwares seem to be using the same audio solution so i think some 3rd party provider is the root of this issue and these softwares we use are victims of that poorly made software as well.

Comment: Gamechanger, thanks!!